# How do I use a an already running .Net Core WorkerService in a web app?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices, blazor

I'm trying to get access to a log generated by a worker service in my web app. I've made a test solution:
[image]

I have an ILogGenerator interface to generate log and a worker which implements it:

```
public interface ILogGenerator
{
    event EventHandler<string> LogGenerated;
}

public class Worker : BackgroundService, ILogGenerator
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> LogGenerated;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var log = $"Worker running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now} {new Guid()}";

            LogGenerated?.Invoke(this, log);

            _logger.LogInformation(log);
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

From Startup in my web app, I'm adding it as a hosted service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        services.AddTransient<WorkerConsumer>();
    }
```

I have a workerconsumer that I want to print the log to the console:

```
public class WorkerConsumer
{
    public WorkerConsumer(ILogGenerator worker)
    {
        worker.LogGenerated += Worker_LogGenerated;
    }

    private void Worker_LogGenerated(object sender, string e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I add both projects to startup:
[image]

When I fire up the application I get this error.
[image]

If I don't call the worker consumer, it works, but I get two WorkerService1's created.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        //services.AddSingleton<WorkerConsumer>();
    }
```

If I don't add the worker service to start up, and I inject the worker consumer in the index page, it works, but, the worker service is no longer running as a separate console application.

Update 1:
My Program.cs of the WorkerService looks like:

```
namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    // services.AddTransient<ILogGenerator>(l => l.GetRequiredService<Worker>());
                });

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

The Startup.cs ConfigureServices of my web app looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            // services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            services.AddTransient<ILogGenerator>(l => l.GetRequiredService<Worker>());

            services.AddTransient<WorkerConsumer>();
        }
```

I start the worker service first, then the web app and I get:
[image]

My understanding is the worker service gets registered to the host, and the web app should be able to pull that worker service from the host, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

As per your error message, you have a problem with dependency injection.

This is probably happening because you forgot to register the ILogGenerator interface with its respective implementation in IServiceCollection.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Worker implements ILogGenerator, which is registered as a hosted service.

Answer (score 0):

To work your code need an instance of `ILogGenerator` share by the publisher and observers. I'll do something like that instead:

**LogGenerator**

```cs
public class LogGenerator : ILogGenerator
{
     public event EventHandler<string> LogGenerated;
     public void OnLogGenerated(string log)
     {
        LogGenerated?.Invoke(this, log);
     }
}
```

**Worker**

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly LogGenerator _generator;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, LogGenerator generator)
    {
        _logger = logger;
       _generator = generator;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var log = $"Worker running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now} {new Guid()}";

            _generator.OnLogGenerated(log);

            _logger.LogInformation(log);
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to tell the DI container what to do when an `ILogGenerator` is requested:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.AddSingleton<LogGenerator>();
            services.AddTranscient<ILogGenerator>(p => p.GetRequiredService<LogGenerator>());

            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }
```

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question with the results. it says the worker is not registered.

Comment: Thank you, agua. I'm able to launch when running from the blazor web app, but can I launch the WorkerService1 project separately and connect to it in the startup of the blazor web app?

Comment: You can't subscribe to events in another process.

Comment: @user1749865 If that run on separated processes then no you cannot. Consider using SignalR in this case.